# Change email header in php pear mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I'm trying to figure out how send email from php using google's SMTP servers, but change the FROM header to match my domain. The email sends fine, but the recipient sees it sent from myemail@gmail.com, rather than me@mydomain.com. I'm using php pear mail to send.

```
require_once("Mail.php");

$from = "Me <me@mydomain.com>";
$to = "Zach <myemail@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "****";
$password = "****";


$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
  'auth' => true,
  'username' => $username,
  'password' => $password));

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);     

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a ssl encryption. Google can help you http://www.google.com/search?q=pear+mail+ssl

Comment: Thanks for the advice, though this didn't solve the problem for me.